# Does My Pseudocode Match My UML Activity Diagram?

Tags: switch-statement, uml, flowchart

I have the following code (just as pseudo-code):

```
switch (expression)
{
   case (ONE)
   {
      #if(FLAG==ON)
         Function1()
      #endif
      break;
   }

   case(TWO)
   {
      if(x==y)
      {
         Function2();
         expression = THREE;
      }
      break;
   }

   case(THREE)
   {
      Function3();
   }

   default:
   {
      Function4:
      break;
   }
}
```

I tried to create a UML activity diagram (see attachment) and not sure if I'm correct on some point:

- Are these 2 "flow final" points correctly mapped or they should go together into one "flow final" point ?
  -Also note that the last CASE don't have an break statement.

Will be thankful for any feedback!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case two has a `break`, therefore it will not call case three afterwards. Even though case two sets expression to `three`, the expression is not evaluated at that point, therefore case three will not be executed.
Case three has to call the default case, because it does not have a `break`.

The unlabeled connection from the `expression` decision node to the ActivityFinalNode is wrong. That path does not exist in the pseudo code because a switch statement always executes at least one case or the default. In addition, all of the flows exiting your `expression` decision node must have a guard (e.g., `[expression == ONE]`). Each guard must be disjunct from all the other guards for this decision node.

A FlowFinalNode (the one with the X) also does not strictly have the same meaning as an ActivityFinalNode (the one with the circle). You should use a FlowFinalNode only to end a forked thread of control. (From the spec: "A FlowFinalNode is a FinalNode that terminates a flow by consuming the tokens offered to it.") In either case, in this model, a FlowFinalNode or ActivityFinalNode is only correct as long as there is no more code below the switch case because `break` only ends the switch case.

Also, flows do not "flow through" merge nodes, they end on the border in an arrowhead. If I was your TA you'd lose points for that, as well as for the decision node with the label in it, which is not in the UML Standard.
Oh right, and for the missing square brackets on the guards.

[uml-diagrams.org](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/software-resolve-issue-uml-activity-diagram-example.html) is a very good resource for UML, if you do not want to read the superstructure itself.

Comment: Case two has a break, you are right. But after the Function2() is finished within case two, the expression is set to case(THREE). So this means I mus have a connection to case THREE, but maybe I represented it wrong on the diagram, right?

Comment: The expression is set to THREE, but the only point where this expression is evaluated is `switch (expression)`. You need to know how a switch case statement works, before you can make an activity diagram of it.

Comment: Edited; the decision node with one exiting flow splitting up for the cases is not UML standard conform afair, but i would accept it in class, to keep the students from drawing four different arrows in parallel.

Comment: There is one other problem to point out: the pseudo code does not re-evaluate `expression` after it is reset. Thus, it cannot must not connect to the merge diamond in the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code represents a state machine and not an activity flow.

Sure, you can also write it as activity, but that does not seem to be reasonable.

FWIW: you model a conditional compile (#if) as flow. This is completely wrong. You need two models. One with the #if being true and one where it is false. This is no runtime condition.

Comment: His intent might have been to write a state machine, but his code is a very confused switch case statement, which i personally would model in an activity diagram.

Comment: @Eashi As said: YMMV. `expression` can be seen as state switch and the labels are the states that can be taken. Especially when you see state transitions inside the switch. Usually a state machine is converted to a switch statement.

Comment: @ThomasKilian: I was going to up-vote your answer, until I got to the last paragraph. First, it's unclear what language this is. (Velocity uses #if for a normal if!) Second, optimizing a condition at compile time shouldn't affect the specification of what needs to happen. That flag could inefficiently be tested over and over again and be functionally equivalent to a compiler preprocessing step.

Comment: @JimL. This code uses if and #if, so I assumed it is a pre-compiler directive.